# why the Php function does not return proper value?

Tags: php, function

I have got a small php function that does not return any value that I can see and I seek your assistance

```
function getAllVotes($id) {
    $votes = array();
    $q = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $id";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if (mysql_num_rows($r)) {
        $row      = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
        $votes[0] = $row['vvotes_up'];
        $votes[1] = $row['vvotes_down'];
    }
    return $votes;
}


// $id = $_POST['id'];


$id = 3;
$cur_votes = getAllVotes($id);
echo $cur_votes[1];

?>
```

now the

```
echo $cur_votes[1];
```

does not print any thing on my screen how ever the $cur_votes actually is an array and I can confirm that by

```
echo $cur_votes;
```

Which returns " Array "

I don't understand why $cur_votes[1]; does not return me any thing. Could you please help me ? 
thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($cur_votes);`?

Comment: Try `echo $cur_votes[0];`

Comment: $cur_votes[0] is also without any output.

Comment: Result to var_dump is array(0) { }

Comment: So you're getting an empty array - does the row with id 3 exist?

Comment: Where is `$tbl_name` defined?

Comment: $tbl_name="wp_wppa_photos"; at the begging of my php. the row number 3 and id = 3 also exist and has value in my sql

Comment: Are you sure it's `$row['vvotes_up']` not `$row['votes_up']`?

Comment: These are my exact copy of the sql columns " Full texts  vid  vtitle  vlink  vvotes_up  vvotes_down  id "

Comment: Have you seen the value, function getAllVotes return "print_r($cur_votes )". If its returning empty array, make sure your db connection and sql query is correct.

Comment: `$votes` is always returned as an array. The `if` statement is failing, given that `mysql_num_rows()` returns `false` on failure or the number of rows on success.

Comment: Where is $tbl_name being set? Are you sure its correct?

Comment: print_r($cur_votes ) returns Array ( ) and rest assured my sql connection is correct.. in fact I can run the php out side of the function and I get values out of $votes[0] and $votes[1] with correct values

Comment: $tbl_name is set in the 1st line and yes its 100 % correct .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the following changes to your query

```
     $tbl_name="tablename"; 
     "SELECT * FROM '{$tbl_name}' WHERE id = '{$id}'";
```

Comment: Integers don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Encouraging SQL injection... Downvoting wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Same result with both .. nothing is returned and the array is empty

Comment: can you check what your query returns?

Comment: Can you state the query ?

Comment: you are using a variable in your query $tbl_name use the curly braces

Comment: I get php internal error out of "SELECT * FROM '{$tbl_name}' WHERE id = '{$id}'"

Comment: could you define the $tbl_name inside your function and try.

Comment: could you define the $tbl_name inside your function and try. you were right. Thanks . That solved my issue